# Spring + Thymeleaf : Getting function argument value from HTML

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

So I have this function :

```
public List<Hotels> returnHotels(String city){
     //somecode
        return hotelsList;
    }
```

That returns a list. I want the city parameter to actually come from the html.
I've created this class for the city

```
@Controller
public class City {
public City() {
}

public String city;

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String City) {
    city = City;
}
}
```

But I have no idea how to make city value to come from the HTML file

Comment: Your model class shouldn't be annotated with `@Controller`, also you should include more context like your template and controller code.

Comment: Hi & Welcome! "To make city value to come from the HTML file", normally the "client" would have to send some request (get, post, ...) to the server. (Typically by "submitting a form", or via JavaScript,...)

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the Thymeleaf documentation to learn the basics: https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html